# Prove that $||f||_p=\sup|\int fg d\mu|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure and $1\leq p\leq\infty$,show that $||f||_p=\sup|\int fg d\mu|$ where the supremum is taken over all bounded measurable functions $g$ that vanish outside a set (depending on $g$) of finite measure, and for which $||g||_{p^\prime}\leq 1$,  ($p^\prime$ is exponent conjugate of $p$) and $\int fgd\mu$
 exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p>1$ : choose sets $A_n$ of finite measure increasing to $X$. LHS $\leq$ RHS is immediate form Holder's inequality. Now consider $g=\frac 1 c I_{A_n} |f|^{p-1} sgn(f) I_{\{x:|f(x)| \leq N\}}$ where $c=(\int_{\{x:|f(x)| \leq N\}} I_{A_n} |f|^{p})^{1/p'}$. you can see that RHS $
\geq \int fg$ for each $N$ and tends to LHS as $N \to \infty$. [$sgn(f)$ stands for sign of $f$]. 
 I will let you handle the case $p=1$

Comment: But, where uses the assumption $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: This approach still holds when the case $||f||_p=\infty$?

Comment: @Zoe I have edited the answer. It does hold even when LHS is $\infty$ and sigma finiteness is required for the argument.

Comment: Thinks, now  I think I can finish proof for the the case p=1