# Norm of function in $L^p$ as a sup of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, holder-inequality

Let $p, q$ be positive real numbers that satisfy $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1.$

I want to show that, if $\color{magenta}{\mathbf{f \in L^p}}$

$||f||_p = \sup \displaystyle \int f \cdot g$,

where the $\sup$ is taken over all $g$ such that $||g||_q \leq 1$.

$\bf{Attempt:}$

For one inclusion, I have that

$\int f \cdot g \leq |\int f\cdot g| \leq \int |f \cdot g| \, {\color{red}\leq} \, ||f|| \cdot ||g|| \, {\color{blue} \leq } \, ||f||_p$,

where I have highlighted the use of ${\color{red}{\mathrm{Holder}}}$ and the fact that ${\color{blue}{||g|| \leq 1}}$.

How do I show the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Do we have $\sup \int f \cdot g$ or $\sup \int \left| f \right| \left| g \right|$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh We have $\sup \int f  \cdot g$. See the edit; I forgot a possibly critical assumption.

Comment: IIRC you should consider $g = |f|^{p-1} \operatorname{sgn} f$, note $pq-q = p$, so $g$ is in $L^q$.

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to prove that if $\|f\|_{L^p} = 1$, then $\mathcal I(f):=\sup_{\|g\|_{L^q} = 1 } \int fg = 1$. Indeed, if this holds, and $ f\neq 0$, then applying this to $\tilde f := f/\| f\|_{L^p}$ in the general case, we obtain
$$ 1 = \sup_{\|g\|_{L^q} = 1 }\int \tilde f g = \| f\|_{L^p}^{-1} \sup_{\|g\|_{L^q} = 1 } \int fg.$$
So without loss of generality, set $\|f\|_{L^p} = 1$. We already know that $\mathcal I(f)\le 1$ by Holder's inequality, so set $g = |f|^{p-1} \operatorname{sgn} f$ as in my earlier comment. Then note that $pq-q=p$, so that
$$ \|g\|^q_{L^q} = \int |f|^{pq-q} = \|f\|_{L^p}^p = 1.$$ This implies that
$$ \mathcal I(f) \ge \int fg = \int |f|^p = 1.$$

PS -  one could take a supremum of the absolute value of the integrals as well (see next comment)

PPS - this is almost a duplicate of [Prove that $||f||_p=\sup|\int fg d\mu|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160091/prove-that-f-p-sup-int-fg-d-mu?rq=1) . In fact, I would say that this is a mildly simpler version of that question.